# Fullpage.js - Slides not sliding or showing content

Tags: jquery, html, slide, fullpage.js

I cannot get the content of the slides to show, or have them cycle. The correct 
page link shows up ie. index3.html#secondPage/slide1 ......
But screen stays the same as I use horizonatal buttons or keyboard to move left and right.

Here is my code:
Very standard as I can't even get a rough site going.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=
"text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
            slidesColor: ['#8FB98B', '#DE564B', '#EAE1C0'],
            slidesNavigation: true,     
scrollOverflow: true                
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fullpage">

<div class="section " id="section0">
    <div class="intro">
        <img src="imgs/1.png"  alt="1"/>
        <h1>Sliders navigation dots</h1>
        <p>Create a navigation for your landscape sliders</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1" data-anchor="slide1">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Clickable</h1>
            <p>
                You can even click on the navigation and jump directly to    another section.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide2" data-anchor="slide2">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide3" data-anchor="slide3">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </div>  <div class="slide" id="slide4" data-anchor="slide4">
        <h1>Slide 4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide5" data-anchor="slide5">
        <h1>Slide 5</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Enjoy it</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: Your HTML markup and initialization work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/439/
Check the javascript console.

Comment: No errors in console either. So weird. All of a sudden one day no more sliding. I can view other websites but not my server. Could it be a hosting issue?